# How do I use JSZip to unzip a .Zip File object in memory?

Tags: javascript, zip, jszip

I have a .Zip file that is in memory as a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object. I want to access the individual files and add it to an array of File objects **in memory**. I see several options online but it all requires accessing a physical *.zip* file on a computer. How can I do it without saving it as a physical file?

Comment: Are you using it in a browser or node?

Comment: I think browser? I'm creating the *.zip* file from an HTTP response and want to display the individual files on the UI

Comment: The [JSZIp docs](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples/get-binary-files-ajax.html#fetch-api-js) do that exact thing.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly do this with JSZip, since `File` implements `Blob` you can probably just do `JSZip.loadAsync(yourFileObject).then(zip => { /* do something */ }`. See the [docs](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/load_async_object.html). You'll want to iterate over every file in the archive and create blobs, optimally with `Promise.all()`.

However, for way better performance and smaller size, I would like to point you to my library [`fflate`](https://github.com/101arrowz/fflate). If you're trying to get an array of file objects in `fflate`:

```js
// If you aren't using a bundler, see the CDN instructions in the docs
import { unzipSync, unzip } from 'fflate';

// multithreaded = false is slower and blocks the UI thread if the files
// inside are compressed, but it can be faster if they are not.
const getFiles = async (zipFile, multithreaded = true) => {
  const zipBuffer = new Uint8Array(await zipFile.arrayBuffer());
  const unzipped = multithreaded
    ? await new Promise((resolve, reject) => unzip(
        zipBuffer,
        (err, unzipped) => err
          ? reject(err)
          : resolve(unzipped)
      ))
    : unzipSync(zipBuffer);
  const fileArray = Object.keys(unzipped)
    .filter(filename => unzipped[filename].length > 0)
    .map(filename => new File([unzipped[filename]], filename));
  return fileArray;
}

console.log(someFileObject);
// File { ... }

getFiles(someFileObject).then(console.log)
// [File { ... }, File { ... }, ...]
```